# sql query for giving specific value to half year

Tags: sql

I need a sql query for this case like(consider the case half_yearly(6mnths),then I need to get for now  that is:

- 2015(7th mnth to 12th month) as zero
- 2015(1st mnth to 6th mnth ) as -1
- 2014(7th mnth to 12th mnth) as -2

likewise decreasing minus values backwards and increasing values from 2015

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Show us your code you wrote up to now and where you struggle

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle you can use **months_between** function:

```
SHOW TRUNC(months_between('06Jul2005' '17Jul2003')/ 6,0)
SHOW TRUNC(months_between('29Feb2000', '30Sep2000')/6,0)
```

For Sql Server you can use **datediff** function

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(month,'2014-08-05','2014-06-05')/6) AS DiffDate
```

Source: [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_x_monitor004.htm) and [Sql Server](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)